# Javascript retrive values from MS Access based on textbox value

Tags: javascript, sql, ms-access

I probably have a simple issue which I cannot figure.

I have a textbox ID "date_added" and have written a JavaScript sql statement to retrieve values based on this textbox value to make it dynamic.

```
var dateadded = document.form_name.date_added.value;
var currentuser = "SELECT * FROM productivity WHERE date_added='dateadded';";
```

If i replace 'dateadded' with an exact date (e.g. 7-May-2014) I am able to retrieve results.
seems like i have my syntax incorrect.

kindly help. thanks!

Comment: The date you are getting may be in a different format try printing and checking it once.

Comment: Is the textbox in a form that's part of your access database or do you have a web page talking to this database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct method to pass date from variable dateadded

```
var currentuser = "SELECT * FROM productivity WHERE date_added='"+dateadded+"';";
```

you are passing dateadded as a text and not as a variable holding date value

Comment: that worked like a charm!! thanks for the quick revert